# $_POST didn't get values after form submit

Tags: php, http-post

I am posting some variables within the same page but $_POST get an empty value.
For HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<table><tr>
    <td>Product Name :</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="searchname" name="productName" value=""/></td>
    <td class="pc">Brand Name :</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="searchname" name="brandName" value="" /></td>
<tr>
    <td>Category Name :</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="searchname"  name="category" value="" /></td>
</tr></table>

<input type="submit" class="fdasearch" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

For PHP

```
if(empty($_POST['productName']) && empty($_POST['brandName']) && empty($_POST['category'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product";
    $getAllProduct = $db->select($query);
}elseif(isset($_POST) || !empty($_POST)){
    Setting variables from $_POST and make a search
}
```

I type "shoes" in productName
and then i used var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')), i get

> string(72)
>   "productName=shoes&brandName=&category=&productName=&brandName=&category="

When i used var_dump($_POST), i get

> array(3) { ["productName"]=> string(0) "" ["brandName"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["category"]=> string(0) "" }

I don't know how file_get_contents works but it seems there's a value but it didn't populate $_POST variable. I want $_POST to have a value in order to make the search.

Comment: Are you using Ajax or form posting?

Comment: Are you using `Form` tag and `submit` button to post data?

Comment: I forgot to post my full code. now it's fixed

Comment: I think this code should work, same code  is working on my system  without any changes

Comment: @Akhilendrayadav Yeah! That should be able to work. When i used in the localhost, it works. So, i transfer that file to a server and then the post_array become empty after submit. You can see my var_dump results in my question.

Answer (score 0):

first, your condition with empty() needs to be !empty() because you won't never reach your query. When I put "!" it meant that if this value different than empty then do the query.To finish, you need to put the action method because you never call that.
So you have to create a folder call "action" and under this, generate file and call inside the form action="action/function".
Hopefully, It will help you

Comment: I guess his first  `if` condition is for  if user click  without  any input  value,  If  user puts any value e.g Product, brand,  then it will go in else condition where He write actual search  query.

Comment: @Akhilendrayadav He said exactly what i am doing right now. If there's no post values, i display all the data from the table and if there's a post value, i do a search query with these variables. I wrote the sql in these two conditions and The form action ="" code let u post the variable to the same page. That's what i think and i have already tried with <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>

Comment: No need to set an `action` attribute on forms. If it isn't provided, the data will be sent to the URL of the page containing the form. You can even omit the complete `action=""` and write only `<form>`.

Answer (score -1):

You should set action at form, like that:

```
<form action="yourphpfile.php" method="POST">
```

When i set action it works fine.

If you are in same file, this code works perfect:

```
<?php

    if(empty($_POST['productName']) && empty($_POST['brandName']) && empty($_POST['category'])){
        echo "we haven't post request";
    }elseif(isset($_POST) || !empty($_POST)){
        echo "we have post request";
        var_dump($_POST); exit;
    }

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <table><tr>
                <td>Product Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="searchname" name="productName" value=""/></td>
                <td class="pc">Brand Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="searchname" name="brandName" value="" /></td>
            <tr>
                <td>Category Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="searchname"  name="category" value="" /></td>
            </tr></table>

            <input type="submit" class="fdasearch" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Return is:

```
we have post request

    array(3) {
     ["productName"]=> string(4) "dsad" 
     ["brandName"]=> string(4) "dasd" 
     ["category"]=> string(5) "dsada" 
    }
```

Comment: i am posting the data in the same php file. So,i think action="" will be enough. i have already tried "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>". Thanks anyway for the advice

Comment: Yes i have checked with ur code. And my code suppose to be working in the localhost. but when i uploaded that file on a server, the code begin to show error like i mentioned above. The post_array becomes empty after submit.

Comment: Can u guide me how to do it? I am still naive at writing code.